# loading multiple csv files in single postgres table

Tags: database, postgresql

my postgres version is 12.4 , I'm loading multiple csv files into single table, The problem here is every time firing below command is not good ,any other alternative (or) suggestions are there?

```
COPY testemail FROM '/md-data/vamshi/s3data/test_Hash_2021.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
COPY testmail FROM '/md-data/vamshi/s3data/test_Hash_2025.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
COPY testmail FROM '/md-data/vamshi/s3data/test_Hash_2026.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
 ..............etc
```

and below command also i tried, but its not working,

```
 COPY testemail FROM '/md-data/vamshi/s3data/t*.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

Comment: Why do you think the first one is "not good"?  `copy` doesn't support wildcards. If you want to automate this, write a shell script that iterates over the files and runs COPY for each of them. Or write a shell script that copies all files into one large file, then run the COPY once

Comment: can u please guide me in the shell script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load all files using:

```
 cat /md-data/vamshi/s3data/test_Hash*.csv | psql -c 'COPY testemail from stdin CSV HEADER'
```